# How to put all the elements from the array as one variable each one

Tags: javascript, arrays, coordinates

I have a array like this (It's created dynamically so the length is variable):

`var coord_list = [[-7.84 , 12.32],[-8.30 , 10.42],[-11.84 , 12.32]....]`

The thing is that i need to put each element(coordinates) `"[-7.84 , 12.32]"` into a turf module that is:

`turf.lineString([[-7.42,9.125],[-8.43,9.800]]...(all of them), {name: 'line 2'});`.

I try to put the `var coord_list` array directly but it doesn't work even it's the same structure inside.

```
turf.lineString([coord_list], {name: 'line 2'}); --> Gives the Error: coordinates must be an array of two or more positions
turf.lineString(coord_list, {name: 'line 2'}); --> Gives the Error: coordinates must contain numbers
```

How can I put each one into the turf formula?

Comment: can't understand your question

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean? Are you getting errors? What are they?

Comment: Well your `coord_list`, appears to be in the correct format, so your second option should do the trick.. But like mentioned, `doesn't work` = `doesn't help`..

Comment: Sorry, i just edit the question with the specific errors.

Comment: It looks like in your dynamically created array of coordinates the numbers are being entered as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [turf documentation](https://turfjs.org/docs/#lineString), an example of the syntax is:

```
var linestring1 = turf.lineString([[-24, 63], [-23, 60], [-25, 65], [-20, 69]], {name: 'line 1'});
```

That is, the first argument is an array of positions.

So your second line seems correct:

```
var coord_list = [[-7.84 , 12.32],[-8.30 , 10.42],[-11.84 , 12.32]....] // is an array of positions
turf.lineString(coord_list, {name: 'line 2'}); --> Gives the Error: coordinates must contain numbers
```

From the error message, it appears that your dynamically generated coord_list has strings instead of numbers

To test this, you can console.log the typeof each position value.

To convert to each value to number, pass each position's x,y value through:

```
let xNum = parseFloat(x);
let yNum = parseFloat(y);
```

before feeding them into `turf.lineString([[xNum, yNum],[xNum2, yNum2],...],{name: 'line 2'})`

In case you have no control over how coord_list is generated, you can fix it like so:

```
let arr = [['-7.84' , '12.32'],['-8.30' , '10.42'],['-11.84' , '12.32']];

let coord_list = arr.map(position => {
    return [parseFloat(position[0]), parseFloat(position[1])];
})
```

Answer (score 0):

From your edit showing the errors I would assume that your coordinates are actually being added as strings and not numbers when creating `coord_list`.